# Unreal Engine 4 -- Casting

Tags: unreal

I am currently developing my first classes in Unreal Engine 4. Coming from using UScript extensively, I'm getting a little bit confused by how typecasting works in pure C++. More specifically, class/object casting.

I am currently putting together a switch statement in MyCustomGameMode which calls upon MyCustomPlayerController for MyCustomPlayerControllerVariable.

The function in question that I am overriding is this one: `virtual UClass* GetDefaultPawnClassForController(AController* InController);`

Currently I'm trying to call the variable with the following line of code, which I know is incorrect, but I'm not sure why:

```
Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController).MyCustomPlayerControllerVariable
```

I am interested in casting the "InController" to MyCustomPlayerController but `Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController)` doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I flagged this as normal programming question, but i was wrong. It is related to game programming as this is UScript.

Comment: @Katu it’s definitely not UScript; the author just said he/she was used to UScript from UE3.

Comment: So is it supposed to be 100% true C++ or some dialect with almost identical syntax?

Comment: @SamHocevar Yeah, yeah. Should not come here before morning coffee.

Comment: @Mario it’s 100% C++ (with some build-time generation of headers).

Comment: @Guest102 “is incorrect”, or “doesn’t seem to work” is not a helpful description of your problem. Be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

`Cast<Foo>` returns a `Foo *`. So the proper way to access your variable should be:

```
Cast<MyCustomPlayerController>(InController)->MyCustomPlayerControllerVariable
```